# Communication between modules and looping through values to create several modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

## Goal

I have five expectations:

1. Solution using modules
2. Communication between modules
3. Dynamic creation of modules
4. local storage using shinyStore
5. Export result in dataframe

### What has worked so far

This is a continuation of the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821617/cant-transform-my-functional-shiy-app-to-one-with-shiny-modules).

I have a Shiny app that currently has two modules, but I have had issues with both of them communicating. The first module Selects any number of species within a Species pool (*SpeciesSelect*), this module is in the file `R/SpeciesSelect.R` within my working directory with the following code.

```
SpeciesSelect_UI <- function(id, SpeciesList){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = ns("SpeciesNames"), label = "SpeciesName", 
                  choices = SpeciesList,
                  multiple = T)
  )
}

SpeciesSelect_Server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # return the reactive here
    return(reactive({input$SpeciesNames}))
  })
}
```

And the second module (*SpeciesCount*) would use those species in order to select how you sample them, and in some cases to count them when the method is equal to pinpoint. This is stored in `R/SpeciesCount.R` and the code is as follows:

```
SpeciesCount_UI <- function(id, Species){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinyMobile::f7Card(
      f7Flex(
        textOutput(ns("SpeciesAgain")),
        uiOutput(ns("Sampling_type_ui")),
        uiOutput(ns("SpeciesCount"))
      )
    )
  )
}

SpeciesCount_Server <- function(id, Species){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$SpeciesAgain <- renderText({Species})
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$Sampling_type_ui <- renderUI({
      #req(input$SpeciesName)
      req(Species)
      f7Select(inputId = ns("Sampling_type"), 
               label = "Sampling type", 
               choices = c("5m circle", "15m circle", "Pin-point"))
      
    })
    
    output$SpeciesCount <- renderUI({
      if (req(input$Sampling_type) == "Pin-point") {
        shinyMobile::f7Stepper(inputId = ns("Species1"), label = "Species count", min = 1, max = 1000, step = 1, value = 1)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Each of the modules is working well on its own as shown in the following example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)
library(shinyStore)

source("R/SpeciesCount.R")
source("R/SpeciesSelect.R")

SpeciesList <- c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5")

ui = f7Page(
  title = "Show navbar",
  f7SingleLayout(
    navbar = f7Navbar("Hide/Show navbar"),
    f7Button(inputId = "toggle", "Toggle navbar", color = "red"),
    SpeciesSelect_UI(id = "SpeciesList", SpeciesList = SpeciesList),
    lapply(seq_along(SpeciesList), function(i) {
      SpeciesCount_UI(id = i, Species = SpeciesList[i])
    })
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {  
  
  lapply(seq_along(SpeciesList), function(i) {
    SpeciesCount_Server(id = i, Species = SpeciesList[i])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    updateF7Navbar()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have 4 issues that are not working well, first, the **communication between modules**, and then **looping through the results of the first module** to get several of the second module, the localStorage issue, and finally exporting it to a dataframe

### Communication between modules and dynamic UI generation

In order to isolate both issues, for the communication problem, I selected only one species and took out the `lapply` function to see if I can get the *SpeciesCount* to recognise the output of the `SpeciesSelect_Server` and incorporate it into the `SpeciesCount` module, here is the code I ended up with:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)
library(shinyStore)

source("R/SpeciesCount.R")
source("R/SpeciesSelect.R")

LIST <- c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5")

ui = f7Page(
  title = "Show navbar",
  f7SingleLayout(
    navbar = f7Navbar("Hide/Show navbar"),
    f7Button(inputId = "toggle", "Toggle navbar", color = "red"),
    SpeciesSelect_UI(id = "SpeciesList", SpeciesList = LIST),
    SpeciesCount_UI(id = "SpeciesCount", Species = SpeciesSelected())
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  SpeciesSelected <- SpeciesSelect_Server(id = "SpeciesList")
  
  
  
  SpeciesCount_Server(id = "SpeciesCount", Species = SpeciesSelected())
  
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    updateF7Navbar()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the results of the `SpeciesSelect` module are not generating any UI in the `SpeciesCount` module

[image]

### Adding the LocalStorage issue

This app is going to be used in the field, that means, that at time we might get connectivity issues, I have issues at storing the values of the Species Select Module, then for sure I will have issues with the next module this is the shiny app I am using

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)
library(shinyStore)

source("R/SpeciesCount.R")
source("R/SpeciesSelect.R")

SpeciesList <- c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5")

ui = f7Page(
  title = "Show navbar",
  f7SingleLayout(
    navbar = f7Navbar("Hide/Show navbar"),
    f7Button(inputId = "toggle", "Toggle navbar", color = "red"),
    SpeciesSelect_UI(id = "SpeciesList", SpeciesList = SpeciesList),
    lapply(seq_along(SpeciesList), function(i) {
      SpeciesCount_UI(id = i, Species = SpeciesList[i])
    })
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {  
  
  lapply(seq_along(SpeciesList), function(i) {
    SpeciesCount_Server(id = i, Species = SpeciesList[i])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    updateF7Navbar()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And I modified the species select for that also

```
SpeciesSelect_UI <- function(id, SpeciesList){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shiny::selectizeInput(inputId = ns("SpeciesNames"), label = "SpeciesName", 
                  choices = SpeciesList,
                  multiple = T)
  )
}

SpeciesSelect_Server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    # return the reactive here
    observeEvent(input$save, {
      updateStore(session, name = ns("SpeciesNames"), input$SpeciesNames)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$clear, {
      # clear current user inputs:
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = ns("SpeciesNames"), value = "")
      
      # clear shinyStore:
      updateStore(session, name = ns("SpeciesNames"), value = "")
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    return(reactive({ns(input$SpeciesNames)}))
  })
}
```

But nothing gets stored. Maybe creating a module for shiny store is needed?

### Export as a dataframe

This one is tied two point 2:

So lets say I am in the following input set:

[image]

The idea would be to generate a reactive that has the following that frame, that I can then export as a CSV file. I think I can handle the export, but I am unsure on how to generate the data.frame from the dynamic UI:

```
data.frame(Species = c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3"), Method = c("Pin-point","5m circle", "15m circle"), abundance = c(5, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Hey @Chris, not really if you see the function SpeciesSelect_Server, that produces `SpeciesNamesOut = reactive({ input$SpeciesNames })`

Comment: I guess if I'm asking where the function is, a compiler might be doing the same. In above notation it appears it can be either an object or a function, but what environment is it in? Okay, can't imagine how debugging automatic function writing could get tricky. Is it called before the server knows about it, has written it?

Comment: The name `SpeciesNameOut` is only known within the scope of that module. Within your app scope, you need to assign the output of your first module to a reactive with its own name. This reactive can be used to trigger your next module.

Comment: Thanks @SmokeyShakers, could you help me out with that? I will try to work it out, but it would be amazing if you can generate an answer

Comment: @DerekCorcoran Can you explain a bit more the dynamic part of the ui? Is `SpeciesName` supposed to be used once? Or the user will be changing those values  frequently? Perhaps updating a dataframe dynamically and then save it to a csv can be less tricky than mantaining all those ui's. Finally, It looks like the shinyStore is supposed to be initialized only once inside the app so the data will need to be passed into the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Your first module is probably already silently returning the reactive but for clarity you can make it explicit. In you first module, return a reactive:

```
SpeciesSelect_Server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # return the reactive here
    return(reactive({input$SpeciesNames}))
  })
}
```

Now call the module AND assign its output a name where you'd like to use it (in another module or in your app server), like this:

```
selected_species <- SpeciesSelect_Server(id = "SpeciesList")
```

Now `selected_species` can be called, observed, etc with:

```
selected_species()
```

Comment: Hey @SmoheyShakers, I tried it and didn't work, I will make an edit to show what I tried and maybe you can help me fix the issues